# How Does an Operating System send Sound to its Speakers?

Tags: audio, operating-systems, speakers

I'm doing a task for an assignment and have come across this question which I have found the internet has not answered for me(so far that I can find). I thought I might ask it.
 The answer does not have to be too detailed but if someone could explain the steps on how the OS sends sound to the speakers it would be much appreciated!

Comment: This functionality is handled by a device driver.

Comment: there are multiple answers on many levels...  all of which i could easily find by googling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound is stored digitally. However, to hear sound, you computer has to convert the digital sounds to an analog signal. To do this, your PC must work with the sound hardware (typically a Realtek or Intel audio chip) to convert and process this signal. It places the necessary signal to the speaker port on the back (or front) of the PC. Any speakers plugged into the port will receive this signal and vibrate it's cone according to the received analog signals. The speakers vibrations vibrate the air and eventually your ear drum, where, you perceive the sound.